# Нужна ли запятая? 7

Tags: пунктуация, сравнение

Как заклинание (,) повторяется набор периодически меняющихся местами слов…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если набор слов повторяется *в качестве* заклинания, то запятая не нужна; если набор слов повторяется *наподобие* заклинания (*есть сравнение*), то запятая нужна. Без более широкого контекста могу предположить, что здесь, скорее, *сравнение* и ***запятая нужна***.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Здесь наподобие... Повторяются слова, обозначающие различные экономические и финансовые проблемы в сложившейся сегодня экономической ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Если в Нацкорпусе посмотреть тексты  с этим оборотом, то он  в большинстве случаев имеет значение сравнения, но **не обособляется так же часто, как и обособляется.**

Здесь важное значение имеет интонационная структура предложения, которая во многом зависит **от позиции оборота**. Оборот обычно обособляется в середине предложения в качестве попутного сравнения и реже обособляется  начале или в конце предложения.

Думаю, что здесь обособление не нужно. На оборот падает логическое ударение, паузы нет: Как заклинАние повторяется набор периодически меняющихся местами слов…

**Примеры:**

Антоша пошел, внедряя в себя, как заклинание, одну мысль,

Она уже так привязалась к этому выражению, что повторяла его как заклинание.

Да, только так, они сговорились, чтобы оклеветать меня, ― как заклинание повторил он.